# PHP not reaching the function

Tags: php

This code should return an array containing data from a WAMP server       containing some entries about followers. Unfortunately it doesn't. Any help please?

```
<?php

include('ConnectionManager.php');

function getfollowers()
{
    print "check";
    //String query
    $query="SELECT * FROM `followers` order by 'followerid'";
    //execute query
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    //3mel array isma followers
    $followers=array();
    //jeeb number of rows 

    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        while($followers=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $followers[]=$followers;
        }
        return $followers;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you indent your code properly? Especially if you expect errors in it?

Comment: sorry,am new to php and i thought its a small code that is easy to understand.

Answer (score 5):

You're re-declaring `$followers` inside your loop. Change it to something else

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $followers[]=$row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your issue is:
    `$followers[]=$followers;`

you are overriding it.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $followers[]=$row;
}
```

should fix the issue